# Fetching one to many relation values using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, core-data, nspredicate

I have core data model with entities department and employees with to-many relationship from department to employee (department-->> employee).I need to fetch all the departments with employees joining date between two dates.

How to Set the predicate for this  ???

Thank You....

Comment: I would not consider this a duplicate, in particular because the other question is unclear and none of its answers has been accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a SUBQUERY here:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(employees, $e, $e.joinDate >= %@ AND $e.jointDate >= %@).@count > 0",
     fromDate, toDate]
```

`employees` is the to-many relationship from *Department* to *Employee*.

(See [expressionForSubquery:usingIteratorVariable:predicate:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionForSubquery%3ausingIteratorVariable%3apredicate%3a) in the "NSExpression Class Reference", where a similar problem and the SUBQUERY solution is documented).